# uppercaseString of IBOutlet UITextField.text crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, iboutlet

I'm running Xcode 6.3 beta 1 with iOS 8.3 beta 1 in the iOS Simulator. I have a `UITextField` `@IBOutlet` of which I'm trying to get the `uppercaseString` property of its `text` property, like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!

@IBAction func calledAfterUserAction(){
    let capitalized = field.text.uppercaseString
}
```

The above workflow will cause a crash. After turning on Zombie Objects, I can see the following error:

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7b689cd0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: You'll need to post your crash log.

Comment: Forgive me, I forgot to include it in the original post. I added this above, but after turning on Zombie Objects, I can see the following error: `*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7b689cd0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem - very glad you posted this so that I knew I wasn't crazy!

I've discovered that the simple "uppercaseString" method fails with a deallocated object error, while the extended version that takes a Locale *works*.  I'm guessing there is an internal Apple bug over handling default locales...  Change your code to:

```
let capitalized = field.text.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! This bug is the weirdest thing, not only because of its incredible specificity of case (if you create a normal `String` and try this, everything works as normal), but also if you call it in a `println` statement, it actually works before crashing. Anyway, I'm totally filing a bug report with Apple later

Comment: THE weirdest bug of all time! Thank god I found your post, thank you so much :)